# Objeto JSON(MongoDB) pasarlo a objeto Java

Tags: java, android-studio, json, mongodb

Tengo una query en la bd de mongo DB que devuelve los objetos en JSON tal que así:

```
[Document{{_id=5e96f76d1c9d44000008f240, nombre=Jesús, puntos=100}}, Document{{_id=5e9ddd81fabbbd2e07a76bee, nombre=hola, puntos=10}}, Document{{_id=5e9ddddbfabbbd2a99adc314, nombre=holaaa, puntos=10}}]
```

**Esta es la query que uso en Android Studio**

```
 Task<List<Document>> itemsTask = findResults.into(new ArrayList<Document>());
        itemsTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<List<Document>>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Document>> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    items = task.getResult(); //List<Document>
                    Log.d("app", String.format("successfully found %d documents", items.size()));
                    for (Document item: items) {
                        Log.d("app", String.format("successfully found:  %s", item.toString()));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("app", "failed to find documents with: ", task.getException());
                }
                Log.v("tag", String.valueOf(items));
            }
        });
```

¿Cómo podría parsear los objetos de **items** para obtener mis dos propiedades(nombre,puntos) por separado en objetos java?

Comment: Si `Document` es un objeto de tipo [Document Class](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html), sólo debes usar el método [`toJson()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--) del mismo. Luego ya puedes usar el parser de Java para convertir tu JSON en un Objeto. Aunque de por sí, ya `Document` es un objeto, no entiendo al final para qué necesitas otro. Saludos

Comment: Quiero conseguir simplemente las propiedades de cada campo. Por eso decía de parsear el JSON , y ya conseguir cada campo..

Comment: Para eso sólo usa el método [`get()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/org/bson/Document.html#get-java.lang.Object-) sobre cada documento. Por ejemplo: `String nombre = item.get("nombre");`. Con eso ya lo tienes. Es que cada `item` es de tipo `Document`, y a la vez `Document` es un Objeto, por lo tanto hereda el método `get()` del tipo Objeto. Saludos

Comment: Gracias todo solucionado

Answer (score 1):

En java existe una clase llamada ObjectMapper, esta clase tiene múltiples funcionalidades, como la de pasar un objeto a un json o viceversa.

```
Document doc = null;
try{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    doc = mapper.readValue(tuJSON, Document.class);
}catch(Exception e){}
if(null == doc){
    log.e("No se pudo procesar");
}else{
 // resto del código.
}
```

Para que sea posible la transformación es necesario que los campos que tienes en el JSON se llamen exactamente igual que los de la clase que vayas a usar, si por ejemplo falta 1 campo que no has declarado en el Java, dará error, **no sé si podrás agregar la anotación** :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Esta anotación se usa para cuando no encuentre algún campo (no lo has declarado o lo has escrito mal, etc). En vez de fallar y arrojar un error, lo ignora.